# Yii Asset issue: some js files are not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, yii, assets

I am currently developing a module for yii application and some of my js file are not loading here is my structure in view/main.php:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/js/uiLoader.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

bootstrap.min.js and uiLoader.js are working fine however highcharts.js is not being loaded I get 404 not found on console.. Anybody experienced this?

Comment: do you have js file in your module assets js folder?

Comment: I do have js file in my module

Comment: can you post assetUrl and actual path of js files.?